# Dom element not the same after javascript render in IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, backbone.js, render

After calling the render event in javascript inside of ie9 the dom object for an ID isn't the same.

This is what I'm doing

```
var SomeView = Module.SomeView= Backbone.TemplatedView.extend({

render: function(){

    //This is true
    $("select#someSelectId").get(0).form === $('#FormContainingSelectors').get(0)

    // This is no longer true when IE 9 finishes a render

    SomeView.__super__.render.call(this);

    //some more code here
    }
})
```

It works in Chrome and Firefox and ie10+  but not in ie9 for some reason.

Can anyone explain why it's happening?

Comment: Can you post the exact pieces of code that are failing, or create a JSFiddle? There is nothing in your current code snippet that would lead me to believe there is a problem.

Comment: For one, you should not be accessing the `__super__` property of the object, see https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/pull/787#issuecomment-3143358.